# How to parse this JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, json

It's stored inside MongoDB and passed to my view file with `json_decode.`

Using PHP, how can I grab the values from within?

```
"environment" : {
            "_id" : "QU",
            "name" : "QA Unstable",
            "streams" : "unstable",
            "hosts" : [
                    "deployclient1",
                    "deployclient2"
            ]
}
```

Comment: print_r(json_decode($str,true)); ?

Comment: Your JSON snippet isn't well formed. You need to enclose it in curly braces

Comment: When making queries to MongoDB using `MongoClient` class (PECL extension for Mongo), the class automatically deserializes the data to a PHP Array.
You may consider storing the data 'environment' as structured data itself inside Mongo so that you never have to deal with calling json_decode explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now to actually answer the question since you already know of `json_decode`:

> Using PHP, how can I grab the values from within?

`json_decode` will evaluate the JSON string into a object in PHP (by default) which means you can use basic dynamic accession syntax to get to your values, i.e. to get `_id`:

```
$object->environment->_id;
```

Or a host:

```
$object->environment->hosts[0]
```

That will return: `deployclient1`

Answer (score 4):

Use `$array = json_decode($json_string, TRUE);`. Second variable makes it array if you supply `TRUE` or object if you omit it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to wrap the string in curly braces...

```
$str = '{"environment" : {
            "_id" : "QU",
            "name" : "QA Unstable",
            "streams" : "unstable",
            "hosts" : [
                    "deployclient1",
                    "deployclient2"
            ]
}}';

print_r(json_decode($str, true));
```